# What is another way to describe an action based on a previous action?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases

In a turn-based game, each player's turn is based upon the turn their opponent took before them. You could say that each action taken in the game is an action based upon the previous action taken in the context of this game.

Is there a word or phrase that describes each individual action in this chain-of-events more succinctly?

Comment: Perhaps it's not quite right for this *exact* context, but a series of events each caused by or based on the preceding one can be called ***knock-on events***. Preceded by, say, ***consecutive*** or ***serial*** if there's a risk *all* the events might be wrongly understood to emanate from a single "trigger" event that came first.

Comment: Subsequent, perhaps?

Comment: The actions sound to me like "alternating responses."

Comment: Not sure whether you mean the causal link/dependency, or the position of each turn. Try dictionary searches for precursor, antecedent, prior / following, consequent, later; and thesaurus entries for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **[contingent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/contingent_2)**

> depending on or influenced by something else:
>   *Buying the new house was contingent on selling the old one*

In your example, each move is dependent upon, and influenced by the previous one.

Comment: So I could say "contingent move" or "contingent action"? Now I'm looking for a noun that matches this adjective.

Comment: You could say *A was contingent on B*. The phrase *contingent move* could  apply to B.  It also could be taken to mean an anticipatory move subject to confirmation, retraction or modification based on a subsequent move.

Comment: The term *response* suggests an action based on a prior action or state.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "each turn is a **countermove**." 
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/countermove?q=countermove

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *cascading* as you mentioned there is a chain of events where each action is affected  by the previous action.

> **cascade** *noun* something arranged or occurring in a series or in a succession of stages so that each stage derives from or acts upon the product of the preceding - [*MW*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cascade)

I've even found a usage in a book about game design:

> Like pinball and SUNBURN!, similar **cascading actions** occur in the game, but less in pursuit of player goals and more in the spirit of experiencing a world that seems alive. 
> <sub>*[Games, Design and Play: A detailed approach to iterative game design](https://books.google.es/books?id=usQwDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&lpg=PT50&dq=%22cascading%20actions%22%20game&source=bl&ots=-is4W2BCUv&sig=ACfU3U0dzmQDnN7Z_DYrKo2llgoTIjVoPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB2vD6k8z4AhWUSfEDHYDLDbUQ6AF6BAgkEAM#v=onepage&q=%22cascading%20actions%22%20game&f=false)* - By Colleen Macklin, John Sharp</sub>